# Is there any P2P GIS or SDI?

Tags: spatial-database, infrastructure

Have you heard/read about a distributed SDI (Spatial Data Infrastructure) or GIS ?

I'm thinking on a system that uses something similar to the torrent protocol for managing spatial data and also be able to perform spatial analysis, geoprocessing and visualization in a distributed way without a centralized provider.